# Question on historical misconceptions on a specific group of people. Is it allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've been thinking about asking such a question and when I say "***misconception***", I do mean it as "***a view or opinion that is incorrect because it is based on faulty thinking or understanding***."

The purpose of my question is -- because I see quite a few questions that's just plain wrong (i.e. historians and newer research told us so) -- so I would like to know why the assumptions/misconceptions keeps coming up.

I do wonder, if at all possible, how do I know/find out what are the areas of misunderstanding. I won't ask **why** they have such views (that is personal) but I would like to know **what** it is that they misunderstood about these group of people in history.

**Is this question permitted?**

Comment: I'm thinking on the point of view of "_ethnogenesis_" for Eurasian steppe - which is so broad that it will include *Proto-Indo-Europeans, and the Mongols (which seem like a current trend), and quite a bit more. I see the question of "race" seeping in so often and confusing it with culture ... i'm getting an itch!

Comment: **Ethnogenesis** (from Greek ethnos ἔθνος, "group of people, nation", and genesis γένεσις, "beginning, coming into being"; plural ethnogeneses) is "the formation and development of an ethnic group." This can originate through a process of self-identification as well as come about as the result of outside identification. (_Wikipedia_)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, if you are explicit about the historical research that shows the "misconception" is actually incorrect, and cite your sources, I can't see why not. It sounds like you'd be providing up-to-date information.

I'm curious though. which group of people are you thinking about?

Comment: Have expanded via comments. Thanks.